# Unsupported decompress method error using GzipStream.Read in c#

Tags: c#, compression

I get the following error: The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.
I got to decode the following gzip compressed base64 string, here is the string:

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\u003d

When I first  use the Convert.FromBase64String method I receive this string when I convert it into a string:

a"\u001f�\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0=R�n�@\u0010\u001d;I��J�Tj\u000f=l�J=Y"؎��c�����`c�-0�q\u0016pa��?����\t�@��O�T]r�^V3��Ӽ�i\u0003��\u0011�\u0001�фf\u00184~6�l��1o���M\vN1��P�\u0013h݆\u0001^3��D��\r�ǧ���!�T��\u0016�W�\u001f �/z�u��:]�?�x\n�\u001dŧ\u0003e�(=�\a��>M���\u0010�\u0016H\u001c_x�b�چ\u0004gK�r��X���j+\a�;�\u0017ڥ��G�͵�~���\u009bh�Z$�۫�<\u001c>\a7�^p�,ܕ�{6�]�(\u001cەgQ�\u0005��\u007f���/tK�\u001dksЏ��1u�n�(�ݢ�Zz�P��ΎE��Q��CO�TŰ\u001f.��\u0019ͧ��~�P��\u0015�N���Q��a��zu1\u0012\u000e�p\u001e�ٞ�B�n��(�&�W����y(�\u0012��Ȉ\"�$�WI��y~�ʁM�S\u0018\u007f#ILR\u001a�^r�>\v苀��=+\b߆\u0019I�\u0018\tO�WW�$%�<C�$H��\b`�|�)�\Б�y\u001c��V��\u0018`�)�%?V�eU��z�\u001aӱ���QW-m"��A#�NU\u0006\u007f~� U雂K�\u0012ê�qUz^U�\u0012\u0001\u001f�_�#ф�w�\vO��4�r^��n4;�ss�\u0019Ws��/H�����0T�&��҈nP\u001c\u0017�\u0003o�r��\u0002\0\0"

could this have something to do with the problem?

Here is my code:

```
    public static string Decompress(string input)
    {
        byte[] compressed = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
        byte[] decompressed = Decompress(compressed);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressed);
    }

    private static byte[] Decompress(byte[] input)
    {
        using (var source = new MemoryStream(input))
        {
            byte[] lengthBytes = new byte[4];
            source.Read(lengthBytes, 0, 4);

            var length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBytes, 0);
            using (var decompressionStream = new GZipStream(source,
                CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                var result = new byte[length];
                decompressionStream.Read(result, 0, length); Error: The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello Mark Adler, I've tried what you said but I still get the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

There is one little oddity in the base64 string, though it should not result in the error message you are getting. the \u003d should be replaced an equal sign (`=`), in order for the base64 decoding to work properly. (I can't tell if the string actually has those five characters at the end, or if it is just a representation of a string with an equal sign at the end. In the latter case, I don't know it wouldn't just show an equal sign as opposed to a unicode escaped representation of an equal sign.)

Otherwise, that base64 string decodes to a valid gzip stream that should decompress with no problem.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it tomorrow. When that is the problem, do you have any idea on how I can replace the /u003d on a dynamic way?

Comment: No, since I don't know how it got there in the first place. (It's a backslash, not a slash.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, I use the GZipStream.CopyTo to a MemoryStream in place of the read function. Here is the code if anyone would need it!

```
   public static string Decompress(string value)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
        byte[] decompressed;

        using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            using var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

            using (var gzip = new GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, leaveOpen: true))
            {
                gzip.CopyTo(outputStream);
            }

            decompressed = outputStream.ToArray();
        }

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressed);
    }
```